# Import and DatabaseDataContext on VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, linq

I was developing a project and I am using Linq.

Everything was good but I did something by mistake and I do not know what i did.

So I can't use Linq and imports are inactive like the screenshot below. What should I do?

[image]

A second problem I now have is that before I made a mistake I was able to use DatabaseDataContext but now I can not use it. It gives me error.

And I have 22 forms with DatabaseDataContext. All of them are not working.

[image]

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: The imports aren't 'inactive'. It just means that they're not currently being used to shorten any references. What's the actual problem you're having?

Comment: If you hover your mouse over the inactive imports, it will tell you why it's inactive.

Comment: If you get a compile error (don't keep it a secret) then you might have fumbled the Project > Properties > References settings.  System.Core must be in the list.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a feature of Visual Studio to show unused references.

The imports that are greyed out are working and active, they are just not being used or referenced anywhere on the page thus they can be safely removed if you want.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** "*I did something by mistake*" - "Tools" menu -> "Options..." -> open "Text editor" -> "Basic" -> "Advanced" then in the pane on the right is an option "Fade out unused imports".

[image]

**2.** If you get a red wiggly line under something, you can hover over that something to get a popup with a link that may solve the problem there:

[image]

Comment: Okay, Thank you.